# How do I get an object from Model to AngularJS variable in JSP?

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp

I send an object to my JSP. If I use JSP syntax, it displays just fine, for example

```
   <div class="mainTitle">
       <h2>${item.name}</h2>
   </div>
```

But when I try to follow instructions for AngularJS I don't get any result. I tried to do it like this

```
   <div class="mainTitle" ng-init="itemAngular = ${item}">
       <h2>${itemAngular.name}</h2>
   </div>
```

But it just doesn't work, there's no output. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try with single quotes ng-init="itemAngular = '${item}' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send your object like Json String. Then, client side, parse your String to JSON

```
var objJson = ${item}; // String;
$scope.item = JSON.parse(objJson);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but what if I need to send an actual Object? It has some nested Objects as well and I need to work with them on my page. My "item" for example has a List<Objects> parameters, and I'd like to use them on my page.

Comment: Gson is a java library help you to convert a object (everything parameters) into a JSON formatted string.